# перебор текста в python

Tags: python

дан текст заканчивающийся точкой вывести все слова из этого текста в котором первые две буквы встречаются еще раз
подряд но в обратном порядке например ПОТОП САВРАСЫЙ
код что ниже все что я мог придумать пожалуйста помогите

text=input('введите текст:')

```
words = text.split(" ")

words = list(filter(None,words))
print(words)

for word in words:
    if word.lower().startswith('k')and word.lower().endswith():
        print(word)
```

Comment: в вопросе не хватает 2 вещей - слов `помогите, пожалуйста` и своего варианта решения (хотя бы словесного)

Comment: спасибо просто я вперве на сайте пришлось потратить немного времени чтобы добавить свои наработки

Comment: Простая логика советует взять строку из двух первых букв, перевернуть ее, и искать вхождение этой перевернутой строчки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

алгоритм:

1. сначала отрезать точку, чтоб не мешала через `[:-1]`
2. разбить строку на слова через `split()`
3. взять первые две буквы слова через `[:2]`
4. перевернуть вырезку через `[::-1]`
5. поискать вырезку можно через `in`
6. перевернуть само слово можно через 4)

Comment: а что за [1] [-1] я почти понимаю что это но не знаю как реализовать

Comment: почитайте про "срезы" - https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html
очень удобное средство

Answer (score 0):

```
textMain = input() #Получаем текст
textReversed = textMain[::-1] #Переворачмваем текст 
print(textReversed)
print(textMain)
```

Comment: мне надо не перевернуть текст а получить слова в которых первые две буквы встречаются но только в перевёрнутом виде